# Como adicionar um item no dicionário que é parâmetro (no __init__) numa superclasse e na subclasse?

Tags: python, herança, dicionário

Desde já agradeço a disponibilidade, estou iniciando os estudos e me deparei com essa questão e não consigo avançar.

Em um exercício de herança tenho que:

Criar a superclasse **Pessoal_Universitario** com um único atributo que seja um dicionário que inclua (Keys): “id”, “nome” e “email”

- Criar as classes **Escritorio**, **Professor** e **Aluno**. Todas herdaram de **Pessoal_Universitário** e os seus dados
- No caso de **Escritorio**, deve adicionar ao seu dicionário de dados o dado “Gabinete”
- No caso de **Professor**, deve adicionar ao seu dicionário de dados o dado “Especializacao”
- No caso de **Aluno**, deve adicionar ao seu dicionário de dados o dado “CreditosAprovados" (integer)

Eu fiquei sem saber como continuar o código nas classes filhas quando devo adicionar um item ao dicionário do **init**.
Segue código:

```
    class Pessoal_Universitario:
        def __init__(self, dados =  {"Nome":None,"ID":None,"E-mail":None}):
            self.__dados = dados
        @property
        def dados(self):
            return self.__dados
        @dados.setter
        def dados(self, dados):
            self.__dados = dados
        def __str__(self):
            return "O pessoal universitário tem os seguintes dados: \nNome - {} \nID - {}  \nE-mail - {}".format(self.__dados["Nome"], self.__dados["ID"],self.__dados["E-mail"])
        def mostrar_dados(self):
            for k, v in self.__dados.items():
                print(k, " : ", v)
   class Escritorio(Pessoal_Universitario):
        def __init__(self, dados):
            super().__init__(dados)
         
        def __str__(self):
            return "O pessoal do escritório tem os seguintes dados: \nNome - {} \nID - {} \nE-mail - {}".format(super().dados["Nome"], super().dados["ID"],super().dados["E-mail"])
        def mostrar_dados(self):
            for k, v in super().dados.items():
                print(k, " : ", v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isto pode ser criando uma cópia do dicionário da superclasse usando a biblioteca `copy`, nativa do Python.

```
from copy import copy


class Pessoal_Universitario:
    def __init__(self, dados):
        self.dados = dados

class Escritorio(Pessoal_Universitario):
    def __init__(self,dados, gabinete):
        super().__init__(dados)
        self.dados = copy(self.dados)
        self.dados["Gabinete"] = gabinete

pessoa = Pessoal_Universitario({"Nome": "Fulano", "ID": 1, "E-mail": "fulano@email.com.br"})
escritorio = Escritorio(pessoa.dados, "Gabinete X")

print(pessoa.dados)
print(escritorio.dados)
```

Comment: Obrigada Diógenes, não tinha feito a cópia e quando adicionava o item no dicionário modificava o principal, também as classes filhas ficam com 2 parâmetros e não queria que acontecesse, porém esse parâmetro integra o dicionário e é isso que importa.  Com o seu exemplo pude fixar melhor alguns conceitos e testar outras soluções, obrigada